# Embedded system hanging

Tags: embedded-linux, freeze

I'm working on an embedded device. I have installed embedded linux (kernel 2.6.37.1) and running my own software (needs internet connection). Sometimes, the device never respond and when accessing via ssh, i notice that ls command (for exple) hangs in the directory that my software uses it to read and write.

When debugging with strace the ls command in that folder, it hangs here :

getdents64(3,

Is there any explanation for that ?

Comment: What kind of device and filesystem are you using for "mass storage"?  I.E. what mounted filesystem is `ls` trying to read from?

Comment: I'm working on openwrt.. The folder is in the overlay layer (jffs2 filesystem).

Comment: Try enabling JFFS2 debugging, verbose mode, in the kernel configuration.  That will require a kernel rebuild  BTW "folder" is Windows terminology.  In *nix filesystems they are called directories.